# node/mysql query returns the same rows multiple times:

Tags: mysql, node.js

I am using node mysql and I have a function that executes a query that selects all the id of a table that looks like this

```
function(callback) {
    return con.query(
      "SELECT TransactionDescriptionPK FROM TransactionDescription WHERE TransactionDescriptionPK > 0",
      function(err, res) {
        if (err)
        return callback(err);
        console.log(res);
        for (var i = 0; i < res.length; i++) {
          //  console.log(res[i]);
        return callback(null, res);
        }
      }
    );
  },
```

But when I log the results it returns the same rows a lot times and I don't know why it's doing that. The function is executed as a async.parallel. What could be the reason it does this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you include part of the code which using this `function(callback) {...}` ?

What are you trying to do at this point:

```
for (var i = 0; i < res.length; i++) {
    return callback(null, res);
    }
```

If you want check res.length you can do it without for statement:

```
if(res.length)
   callback(null, res);
else
   callback(new Error('empty mysql response');
```

Comment: It still does the same thing